# Perform operation on subset of factors

Tags: r

I have a factor variable, condition, that tells me whether subjects took a test or not:

```
data$condition.f <- factor(data$condition, labels = c("notest", "test"))
```

I have a variable, x that contains right (1) and wrong (0) responses to a question.

```
> data$x
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [42] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  1 NA NA  1  0 NA  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
 [83]  1  1  0  1 NA  1  0  1  1  1  1  1 NA  1 NA  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0 NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1 NA  1  0  0
```

The first half of the vector corresponds to those that did not take a test (hence the NAs), and the remainder represent those that did take the test.

I would like to replace the NAs for those that did take the test with 0. I have tried the following code:

```
if (data$condition.f == "test") {

       data$x[which(is.na(data$x))] <- 0   

}
```

But I get the error

```
Warning message:
In if (data$condition.f == "test") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I'm not sure what the exact issue is, although I know it has something to do with the *if* statement. Is there a better way to replace the NAs with 0 for just those that took the test?

Thank you

Comment: Regarding the **warning** (*not* error) message, `data$condition.f == "test"` returns a logical vector the same length as `data$condition.f`. `if (...)` is expecting a single logical value (length-one logical vector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem arises because you are trying to compare a vector (`data$condition.f`) with a string (`"test"`).

How about `data$x[is.na(data$x) & data$condition.f == "test"] <- 0` instead?

**Edit:** I fixed my mistake upon *thelatemail*'s suggestion below.

Comment: That's not right. You are combining two numeric vectors with a logical `&` which doesn't work as intended and will probably end up replacing every value with `0`. `data$x[is.na(data$x) & data$condition.f=="test"] <- 0` is what you want. Try it on `data <- data.frame(x=c(NA,1,2,3,4),condition.f=rep(c("test","notest"),c(2,3)))` for example.

Comment: awesome, thank both of you for your help! @thelatemail 

for future reference, what was incorrect about my original code? It seems as though the if statement I wrote also does the same conditional evaluation (if vector == "blah"), and then within the if statement I tried to assign the value 0 to NAs...

Comment: @butlerbj - nrussell covered that in his comment on your question above